# CoreLocation in WatchOS 3.0

Tags: watchkit, core-location, apple-watch, watchos-3

I'm trying to get a current location from **CoreLocation** in `WatchOS 3.0` on a series 2 watch.  I need to get an up to date location at a regular interval while the watch is stand alone.

Is this possible?

Comment: what you try so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CoreLocation is available on Apple Watch since WatchOS 2.0.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation

You can implement CoreLocation just like you would on iOS.
The Watch Series 2 has his own GPS device, so it would update your location regularly even when running stand alone, just like an iPhone would do.
Runtastic is also using this technique on the Apple Watch.

Does this answer your question, or do you have a specific question regarding this?